# Phantasmal Affliction double save

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Phantasmal Affliction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-affliction)

> Curse: The target believes she has been cursed. She takes a permanent –4 penalty on attack rolls, saves, ability checks, and skill checks for 1 hour per caster level. **After her save to disbelieve, the target attempts a second Will save to negate this effect.**

The part in bold seems to indicate that if you use the Curse option, they get two saves to negate this effect, the second with a -4 (as the curse is in effect at that point). Is this correct?

Comment: It's yet too new for errata or developer clarification. You're likely the first to've noticed any difficulty with the spell.

Comment: Well, we can but wait :-) In the meantime, we are going to run it as I described, I suspect

Comment: As far as I understand: First there's a save to disbelieve. If that fails, the target saves against the proper effect. Is there some complication here or is this effectively an answer?

Comment: I don't see any complication in understanding how this spell works. Is there any answer that can be given that can't be summed up as "Yes"?

Comment: @GreySage The problem is the placement of the sentence *After her save to disbelieve, the target attempts a second Will save to negate this effect.* Were that sentence at the beginning of the curse's description, it'd clearly negate the entire curse, but coming the end makes it unclear if the effect occurs first and afterward can be negated by the second save **or** if the second save occurs to negate the effect *before* the effect occurs.

Comment: As a sidenote, the spell seems to be poorly written. I mean. She takes a **permanent** –4 penalty on attack rolls, saves, ability checks, and skill checks **for 1 hour per caster level**.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the Paizo board about curses and other afflictions.

Save: This gives the type of save necessary to avoid contracting the affliction, as well as the DC of that save. Unless otherwise noted, this is also the save to avoid the affliction's effects once it is contracted, as well as the DC of any caster level checks needed to end the affliction through magic, such as remove curse or neutralize poison.

Therefore, I would read this in the same way as poisons. You would use the DC for the Disbelieve once cast. If the enemy fails, then and only then, **After her save to disbelieve, the target attempts a second Will save to negate this effect.** Both at a -4, or if they fail, they will continue to have said modifier, as with other curses and poisons.

Comment: This answer would be strengthened if it quoted the "Saving Throw Will disbelief, then Fortitude or Will negates (see text)" line of the spell description.

Comment: Neither the spell [*phantasmal affliction*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-affliction) nor the resultant illusory curse  is itself an actual [affliction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions). I'm not sure how those rules apply.

Comment: Per Pathfinder SRD: "From curses to poisons to diseases, there are a number of afflictions that can affect a creature." Curses is an affliction.

Comment: @Krista O, sure, a [curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/curses) is an [affliction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions), but I don't see what that has to do with the spell [*phantasmal affliction*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-affliction) and the illusory curse it can bestow, which says, "The target *believes* she has been cursed." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan - the affliction rules are in effect if the character/creature fails the initial save vs. disbelief once cast on them. If this roll fails, they ARE AFFLICTED with the illusory affliction chosen by the caster (see SRD for reference - last sentence prior to types of affliction the caster can choose from). As such, the affliction save rules apply after the first failure as the illusion is that of an affliction.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the spell is a [Phantasm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/?pid=15359/all-spells/s/summon-thanadaemon/#TOC-lllusion-Phantasm), rules for which mention

> This impression is totally in the minds of the subjects. It is a personalized mental impression, all in their heads and not a fake picture or something that they actually see.

So - the person affected is perceiving clues that makes them think they are affected by the various afflictions. The rules for [disbelief](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/?pid=15359/all-spells/s/summon-thanadaemon/#TOC-Saving-Throws-and-Illusions-Disbelief-) say, in part -

> Creatures encountering an illusion usually do not receive saving throws to recognize it as illusory until they study it carefully or interact with it in some fashion.

Taking the Curse option specifically, I would take this to mean that no disbelief save is allowed until the target tries to make an attack roll, or rolls a skill check, or a save, while under the effect. Or, somehow, examines specifically what's going on, maybe with detect magic, or by trying to make attacks or something similar. Potentially, making a Spellcraft check to identify the spell as it is cast would also provide an opportunity to disbelieve.

Regardless, by the time the person is making a save to disbelieve, they are already under the effects of the illusory curse. So, the save to disbelieve would include the modifier for the illusory curse of -4. Assuming this save succeeds, the illusory curse is still in effect, even though the target has realised it is an illusion. The second save is to break free of that illusion, and would still receive the -4 to save, since the curse is still in effect.

As an added note, the description of the Save line seems inconsistent with the Poison and Disease entries. Although the Curse seems to be in effect even after disbelieving, neither the Poison nor Disease effects mention this. So, I would actually expect that making the Disbelieve save would prevent both of those options from having an effect, even though the save entry implies the opposite.

Answer (score -2):

Surely this is just a save to disbelieve the illusion and then a save to negate the spell from affecting you? Neither has a -4 as the spell hasnt affected you until you miss both saves. Just like many other spells in Pathfinder. The text is just telling you that the target gets two saves rather than one.

I had trouble finding it online but my CRB under Magic -> Saving Throws
"Negates: This spell has no effect on a subject that makes a successful saving throw"

Comment: The [*phantasmal affliction*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantasmal-affliction) spell's saving throw entry says *Will disbelief, then Fortitude or Will negates (see text)*, providing little insight, serving more as a placeholder for the actual effects of the saving throws. And the second saving throw's placement in the spell's description (*after* the curse's effect) makes it unclear when the saving throw penalty applies to the effect that might negate it.

Comment: This is the same answer I previously posted but without the SRD info on saves.